# Can't position div/ul on top of a previous div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to setup a menu of tabs.  I want it to move up so that it is just over the previous div.  However, whenever i move it up, it goes underneath the previous div.  I've tried changing the z-index with no prevail.

http://www.cable-warehouse.com/?page=test&id=156781

Here is the previous div:

```
#product {
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #434649;
    /* background: url(images/prod_bg.gif) repeat-x bottom; */
    border-left:solid 1px #cccccc;
    border-right:solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

Here is the div I want to sit above the previous div:

```
.tabs {  /* div wrapper */
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    top:-30px;
    left:0;
}
.tabs ul { /* tabs */
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    padding-top:4px;
    position:relative;
}
```

How the HTML looks:

```
<div id="product">content here</div>
<div class="tabs"><ul><!-- tabs list --></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the tabs are contained in an element with `overflow` set to `hidden`. In fact, it seems like you've set that style to apply to all `div`s. That is a bad idea, and this is one reason why. Apply `overflow: hidden;` only selectively where needed.

Comment: wow hours are yelling at my computer and it was my ridiculous mistake.  Thank you so much!